# Why does garbage collection take so long (>10ms) sometimes.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm looking at two different projects in Unity in the profiler. One of them is listed to have <10 mb of allocated gc, and it goes up at some rate, and then drops (garbage collection i guess) every 10 frames. The time for the drop occurs is so small that it doesn't affect anything.

Another project, shows in the profiler that i have 300-400 mb allocated gc. It goes up at 1/10th the rate above, but only seems to collect gc every 50-100 mb of allocated gc. This collection ends up taking longer than the frame time.

Is it taking longer because it's scanning through all of the variables in "allocated gc" for stuff that isn't needed any more? If so, how would I go about declaring a variable in such a way that it will not be scanned during garbage collection. I heard about "GC.KeepAlive" but I'm not sure if this would accomplish this.

It's a shame because I just did so much work reducing the amount of garbage produced at each frame (by using object pools), but gc is still happening, and still taking long.

Comment: you  can use the stack instead of the heap for data you don't mutate.  (struct v. classes).  Without knowing more about what you doing it's hard to guess at how to fix it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As a note your "object pools" could actually hurt GC if not done correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm definitely mutating stuff, and they are not always small, but I was hoping to be able to mutate them with minimal garbage generated.

can you elaborate on your second note about object pools hurting gc? How would/could they...what practices should be followed?

Comment: If you are moving around (or creating/destorying) large objects you are going to cause memory fragmentation which can cause the GC issues you are seeing.  If you are doing minor mutations such as changing integer values you should be able to pin the objects to reduce fragmentation.

Comment: If you having loading screens a quick and dirty fix could be to force GC on load so the player isn't effected by glitches.  again, without seeing the code or how it is performming it's hard to give a better suggestion.

Comment: " If you are doing minor mutations such as changing integer values you should be able to pin the objects to reduce fragmentation" . How does one pin objects? Yea, currently the pools are populated at application load. I'm just worried that during the application life, the whole pool(s) is(are) scanned when I know for a fact they should be ignored for gc.

Comment: Just a guess from a noob but I imagine all variables will be "scanned during garbage collection". Remember, when a variable goes out of scope (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) it's eligible for GC, but the GC is very smart; your only worry is to make the variable out of scope at a reasonable pace, not every frame. that said the compiler is smart enough to consider local variables as permanent. Thinking while I type; this is probably less to do with the variables than the size of what they're holding.